# Hear "an explosion noise" or "an explosion sound"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which word fits more *sound* or *noise* in this sentence?

> Suddenly, I heard an explosion sound/noise.

Comment: or "I heard the sound of an explosion".

Comment: If you really want to use this structure, "I heard an exploding noise/sound" sounds more natural than "I heard an explosion noise/sound."

Answer (score 39):

My suggestion: Neither. The phrase

> 'Suddenly, I heard an explosion'

is enough, there is no need to identify the actual sound separately, it's already indicated by 'explosion'.

Comment: *Boom* is an onomatopeic word for explosions that can be used too.  "Suddenly, there was a boom!"

Comment: You can lose "suddenly", too. Explosions are sudden by definition: you can't hear an explosion gradually.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm all for being concise, but I think "suddenly" is valid in this case. The word implies the explosion is both [quick and unexpected](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/suddenly).

Answer (score 7):

Without the context of knowing that it actually *is* an explosion, I would suggest

> Suddenly, I heard what sounded like an explosion.

although other answers may be more appropriate if you can identify the explosion from more than the sound alone.

Answer (score 4):

*Explosion sound* and *explosion noise* both sound wrong to my native-speaker ear.  I would only ever say "I heard an explosion" or "I heard the [sound/noise] of an explosion".

I can't quite figure out *why* this sounds wrong, though.  You certainly *can* use "sound" as part of a compound noun, for instance "flute sound" would be perfectly fine ("flute music" would be more usual, but only because musical instruments are very strongly associated with, er, music).  It might be because *explosion* is an event rather than an object ("crash sound" also sounds wrong).

Comment: It sounds wrong only through disuse. It is *grammatical* but not *euphonic*. Like "white and black" instead of "black and white".

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative as @MeanGreen's answer, I'd say:

> Suddenly, I heard the sound of an explosion.

This ^ is the best alt in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the above suggestion of, "suddenly, I heard an explosion".

As I have a degree in sound, I thought it would be worth mentioning that, in acoustics, there is a difference between sound and noise. Noise is an undesired sound or signal, for example electronic interference. In the context of the environment that this explosion occurred, it might be considered a noise, as it probably wasn't a desired sound in that setting.

https://www.britannica.com/science/noise-acoustics

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on including "sound" or "noise" in the sentence, the adjective form of "explosion" can be used to describe the sound as "explosive".

> Heard an **explosive** sound
>
> Heard an **explosive** noise

The phrase "heard an explosion" is likely better, though, as noted in other answers.

N.b. "explosive sound" may be slight agrammatical for what you're trying to convey. An "explosive sound" would be a a loud and violent sound, but the *source of the sound* is left unstated. An "explosion sound" or "explosion's sound" would be the sound *resulting from an explosion*, even if that sound is quiet or otherwise non-explosive.