# Which fits better "noise" or "sound" and why?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105432/hear-an-explosion-noise-or-an-explosion-sound/105477#105477) I earlier asked created further confusion for me. Some suggested using neither *sound* nor *noise* in that sentence, but what if I were to say this,

> I lived in the war-torn country, Syria, where the constant (sounds/noises) of
>   explosions and gunshots were a norm.

Comment: There are many nouns that could be used in place of _sound_ or _noise,_  e.g.: _din, roar, tumult, barrage..._ (Note that the singular is idiomatic here: _where the constant **noise** of explosions and gunshots **was the** norm._) Unfortunately, this appears to be a proofreading/editorial question.

Answer (score 1):

"Sound" is probably better, but since you want to convey an image there are other more evocative nouns you might try, for example, "the constant **thunder** of explosions and **rattle** of gunfire," among many other options.  Which you choose is all a question of personal style and intended effect.

If you do go with sound it is "sound" not "sounds", "The sound of children playing was interrupted by the roar of a passing train."  I don't know if there is a rule that governs this usage, though, or if it's yet another idiom you have to memorize.

Lastly, the idiom is "**the** norm", not "a norm".  It's short perhaps for "the normal way of things", but I can't find anything on its etymology.